# Найти суммы цифр числа N!(Например для 30!)

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика

Факториал я нашел. `2.6525285981219103E32`. Проблема в Е32. При дальнейшем работе с числом точность теряется и накапливается погрешность. Как без погрешности преобразовать число, что б не было Е

Comment: Используйте арифметику больших чисел
Принципиальных варианта два - либо пытаться впихать 30! в 64 битное целое (или какое там максимальное в java), либо с нуля строить арифметику больших чисел (например,на массивах - неэффективно по памяти, зато наглядно и очень познавательно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если значения не вмещаются в диапазон значений long или int то нужно использовать BigInteger или BigDecimal.
Решение же вашей задачи будет такое:

```
 private static BigInteger factorial(long number) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (long i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: так-то это не решение задачи в вопросе, это подсчет факториала

Comment: хм, видимо я не так понял вопрос.

Comment: А может и правильно понял, просто в заголовке сложить цифры полученного числа, а самом вопросе про факториал. А у BigInteger доступ к конкретным цифрам так же по индексу? или какой-то специальный метод?

Comment: Проблема была в нахождении факториала без `E` сумму цифр найти не проблема)) Спасибо за ответ